# How to return a list of results in MySQL, WHERE only return one

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to return a list of films the actor was involved with. The second statements gives several results, but only the first hit get showed when i run the last statement. It's like the last variable only searches for "first-match".

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, and I'm unsure what search word I could use to find the solution (as I believe this question is answered several times already).

```
SELECT @id := actor_id FROM sakila.actor WHERE first_name = 'Ed' and last_name = 'Chase';
SELECT @film :=film_id FROM sakila.film_actor WHERE actor_id = @id;
SELECT title FROM sakila.film WHERE film_id = @film;
```

[image: Second statement results]
[image: Third statement returns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do something like:

```
select title from sakila.film f 
join sakila.film_actor fa on fa.film_id = f.film_id
where fa.actor_id = @id
```

this joins the last 2 queries into one, and is better than your way or using sub queries in my opinion

Comment: Thanks but do you have a explanation to why? I agree its a cleaner solution, but why wont "my" approach pass trough all the results?

Comment: Well the return of this:
SELECT film_id FROM sakila.film_actor WHERE actor_id = @id;

Will be a list of film_id's..  Im suprised your queries even run.  Im not an expert with MySQL specifically, but i doubt you declared a list of strings for @film_id variable did you?

Comment: No, just the @ tag. Thanks for your help though ;)